# Scheme - takink list from lists

Tags: scheme

If I have list:`((3 4 5) (2 1 4) (4 1 3))` and I want to get only the `(3 4 5)` list, How can I do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(car '((3 4 5) (2 1 4) (4 1 3)))
```

In Scheme given the example you have.